# Airflow scheduling issues

Tags: airflow

Reposting as last time I forgot to include `code` samples.

I've been running into a few issues with trying to get Airflow setup. I have been trying to follow a very basic DAG setup with a single, simple `SQL` script. I have been running into three problems :

1. I was able to get a basic `DAG` running (I can see the `DAG` in the GUI and the effects of its run on the database), but it seems like the `DAG` is not respecting the `schedule_interval` argument. I am trying to get the `DAG` to run hourly, but no matter what change I make, the `DAG` runs on a daily schedule and this is reflected in what I see from the GUI as well.
2. Further, although the `DAG` is able to run its single task smoothly if the `DAG` is run as part of a scheduled run, every attempt I have made at a manual execution of the `DAG` fails. I am not sure as to why this could be.
3. When updating the DAG `start_date` and `schedule_interval`, I have been renaming the `dag_id`, as that seems to be a recommended practice. This has at times triggered backfilled `DAG` execution, but these backfilled jobs also always fail.

The Airflow configuration is the default, other than changing `donot_pickle = True`. Would really appreciate any help anyone can offer on any of the above three issues, as they have seemed impenetrable thus far to me.

Airflow :

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.postgres_operator import PostgresOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

DEFAULT_ARGS = {
    'description': 'For now, a test DAG',
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 7, 19),
    'schedule_interval': "@hourly",
    'end_date': None,
    'owner': 'airflow', #placeholder
    'retries': 3,
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='test',
    default_args = DEFAULT_ARGS,
    )

test_redshift_op = PostgresOperator(
    task_id = 'test_redshift_op',
    sql = 'test.sql',
    postgres_conn_id = 'redshift',
    dag = dag
    )

test_redshift_op
```

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(
  id integer,
  words varchar(255)
)
;

INSERT INTO test(
  id,
  words
)
VALUES
(1, 'test'),
(2, 'finish')
;
```

Comment: You don't need to repost. Please just edit questions as you need.

Comment: 2) *every attempt I have made at a manual execution of the DAG fails*. How?

Comment: 3) *these backfilled jobs also always fail* How? Please include more information like a stack trace or a specific error you are getting and log info as well.

Comment: @PaulCrovella I've flagged the other one as a duplicate of this since this one has progressed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `schedule_interval` is no part of `default_args`. Out of curiosity - where is that code sample from? `schedule_interval` is part of the `DAG` definition:

```
dag = DAG(
  dag_id='test',
  default_args = DEFAULT_ARGS,
  schedule_interval = '@hourly',
)
```

For 2) and 3) it is given that something went wrong but it was not specified what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with all the ambiguity. All the above problems mentioned above were actually resolved when I added the arguments to the appropriate objects instead.